# Verbose NMake Makefiles using CMake

Tags: cmake, nmake

I have been following instructions from the FAQ: [Is there an option to produce more 'verbose' compiling?](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#Is_there_an_option_to_produce_more_.27verbose.27_compiling.3F). I have now:

```
$ cat C:/Program Files/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/Platform/Windows.cmake
[...]
# uncomment these out to debug nmake and borland makefiles
set(CMAKE_START_TEMP_FILE "")
set(CMAKE_END_TEMP_FILE "")
set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE 1)
```

I then regenerate my project, and run nmake:

```
> cmake --version
cmake version 2.8.12.2

> cmake -G"NMake Makefiles" ..\project
> nmake VERBOSE=1
[...]
[ 73%] Building CXX object apps/foobar/CMakeFiles/bla.dir/my.cpp.obj
    cd C:\Dashboards\MyTests\project-build-debug-vista32-nightly\apps\foobar
    C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1.0\VC\bin\cl.exe  @C:\Users\voxxl\AppData\Local\Temp\nm1362.tmp
```

Is there a way to have access to the full `cl` command line ?

Comment: Is there anything in `C:\Users\voxxl\AppData\Local\Temp\nm1362.tmp`?

Comment: nm1362.tmp: No such file or directory

Comment: For me uncommenting the three lines shown above did the trick. As soon as they are uncommented, the full `cl` command line is shown. Maybe this was fixed after the OP.

Comment: Updated FAQ link: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/FAQ#is-there-an-option-to-produce-more-verbose-compiling

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Windows (XP or greater), Command lines are limited in length to 8,191 bytes.

Windows compiler toolsets get around this by allowing the @filepath syntax on the command line.

So VERBOSE=1 is less useful on Windows. But you can always check command line in generated *.make files

For example (path used from question):

> apps/foobar/CMakeFiles/bla.dir/build.make
>   apps/foobar/CMakeFiles/bla.dir/flags.make

Comment: How do we enable verbose logs for Visual Studio generator?